# cordova phonegap barcode scanner camera error

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner

I have searched alot for a solution to this. And only found old answers which don't help.

I am using cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

cordova 6.1.1
barcodescanner 4.1.0
Android 6

I deploy my app on android 6 but get the 'Sorry the android camera encountered a problem' when I attempt to launch the barcode scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the permissions set up in Manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: Doesn't the the barcodescanner plugin for Cordova use ZXing's scan via intent on Android? In that case, you don't need the camera permission in your manifest

Comment: Looks like the plugin I'm using does not give the application permission to use the camera on Android 6. I have had to give the app permission to use the camera manually via Settings -> apps -> (choose app) -> permissions -> select camera